# Image files for iPhone 5/5C/5S

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, retina-display

I have some `png` image files in my project's `Supporting Files` directory that are intended to be shown only in iPhone 5 and later devices (I detect screen size programmatically to set the proper image). This would be a simple question: since all those devices have retina display, should I suffix image files with `@2x`? Even if no standard resolution of such images will be needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the application is intended for iPhone5/5S/5C, then I don't think there is any need to detect "size" since they all are the same size, but if you are making an app which is to work on a device with a diff size, then append '@2x' at the end of the image file name for the 2x image and use the image's name without the .png extension when developing... the API will automatically set the appropriate image.. you don't need to detect size etc..

Comment: The app is intended for all iPhone devices, but I have a particular view where I show a different image depenging on the device, having the standard and high resolution versions of just one image is not enough in this case because artwork is a bit different

Comment: In fact, I have 3 image files for this view I'm talking about: standard and high resolution versions of the image intended for iPhone 3GS/4/4S, and a high resolution version for the image intended for iPhone 5/5C/5S

Comment: The '@2x' is only going to work when the device resolution changes (from normal to retna)... the device size in my opnion, is not going to work with '@2x'

Comment: Knowing that for iPhone 5 and later it will always be retina resolution, no need to suffix file with '@2x' then...